# xlwings Error when I leave the workbook with macro running

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a variety of python functions that I call from xlwings. These functions pull data from my workbook, do things with it (open corresponding csv file, clean the data, perform calculations, etc). Everything works fine if I sit there and watch it, but the moment I try to switch to a program outside the workbook (like Chrome), xlwings gives an error. The specific error depends on where during the program execution it is when I click away, but examples include:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', None, None)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146777998), None)
```

I also have these problems if I click within the workbook (to select a cell or minimize it), but that doesn't concern me. If I manage to leave the workbook, such as when a non-xlwings part of my code is running, I don't get any errors.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
TDM

Comment: Does it work if you hide Excel during the execution with `Workbook(app_visible=False)`? This hides however the whole instance of Excel, not just the Workbook.

Comment: Adding xw.Workbook(app_visible=False) causes the next line of code to fail. The next line is sheetname = xw.Sheet('SheetName'), and it fails with a pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)

Comment: Edit: Adding Application.Visible = False before the vba call of RunPython seems to do the trick. Thanks.